# After save call back don't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set a callback for my Product Model, but the **product** attribute's `discounted_price` doesn't change...

I can't call `self.save` it raises a `stack level too deep`

What am I doing wrong?

**product.rb**

```
after_save :set_discount

def set_discount
  self.discounted_price = self.price - (self.price * self.discount_percentage / 100)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value before saving in BD!

```
before_save :set_discount

def set_discount
  self.discounted_price = price - (price * discount_percentage / 100)
end
```

Also, self not necessary use after `=`

Comment: thank you for the info about the `self not necessary use after =`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `before_save` callback, because `after_save` happens - as the name suggests, after the save has completed

Comment: oh okay I really though it was an after_save needed here, thanks